# Количество комментариев

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите на странице с `id` статьей количество комментариев вывожу таким запросом:

```
$result_c = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE post='$id'",$db);
$comm_sum = mysql_fetch_array($result_c);
echo "<div class='col_comm'>Комментариев: $comm_sum[0]</div>";
```

Но как это сделать если `id` нет т.е мне нужно вывести к каждой статье количество комментариев.
Какой запрос надо сделать или что-то еще? Помогите.

Comment: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,description,date,author,mini_img,view,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE post='$id')AS count_comment FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $num",$db);`

По сути мне надо здесь что-то поменять

Comment: ммм....<br />это вывод новостей? там ты сделай запрос в новости а в процессе вывода, точнее перед самым "красиво выводим всю эту хрень" сделай выборку по результату)) то есть ты же получаешь данные из базы, то есть в цикле у тебя уже есть переменная с ID ну так и подставь её)) или это я уже что то не понимаю??<br /> Сделаем проще, какова структура базы с новостями и структура базы с комментами

Comment: есть отдельная таблица с выводом всей информации(news) и коментариев(comments)

Comment: я не могу разобраться как это нужно делать а статьи пока для меня сложны будет немного проще если вы прокомментируете код

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,description,date,author,mini_img,view,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments JOIN news ON news.id=comments.id)AS count_comment FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $num",$db); 

правильно?
но у меня это не работает

Comment: Посмотрите пример ниже, может так проще будет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю вам надо вывести список статей и количество комментов к ним. Тогда это делается так:

```
 SELECT posts.*,COUNT(comm.id) AS `comments_count` FROM `news` AS `posts` LEFT JOIN `comments` AS `comm` ON (news.id=comments.post)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала почитайте о primary key в mysql чтобы небыло таких вопросов, вообще по сабжу:
Вам в любом случае необходимо какое-то уникальное значение, к сожелению пока СУБД не обладают екстрасенсорными способностями и не могут выбирать по тому чего нет, а по другому тут неполучится...
Вообщем вывод - запрос у вас правильный, реализовываемм primary key int autoincrement - profit...

Comment: Пожалуйста, киньте статью, где можно почитать, а то я нашел только как делать запросы табличные наподобие

     CREATE TABLE example_autoincrement (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         data VARCHAR(100)

Comment: Так у вас всетаки нет unique key'ев? ну тогда на пальцах - поле таблицы уникальное для любой записи, которое всегда существует и никогда не может повторятся, собственно теперь просто сделайте везде себе unique кеи и почитайте про JOINS и вложеные запросы и вы сами сможете решить свою проблему, кстати могу предположить что об индексах вы тоже ничего не знаете :)<br>
Можете еще и о них почитать...

Comment: А можно проще вы сделаете. Мне просто интересно, как реализуется проблема, а времени мало.

Comment: Конечно, я могу вам написать запрос и у вас все будет круто и т.д. Но я этого делать не буду, я вас направил на путь истинный, идти по нему или нет выбирайте сами, да и подождите немного, возможно, кто-то будет "подобрее" меня и просто напишет вам нужный запрос :)

Comment: спаисибо засарказм но вы правы ялучше сам попытаюсь а если не получится тогда вымне поможете ведь так?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, нужно вывести количество комментариев к каждой новости/статье. если так то...

```
    цикл...
$comnum = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news_comments` WHERE `newsid` = '".$res['id']."'"));
```

потом где нужно выводим типа Комментариев: `<? echo $comnum; ?>`

Соответственно $comnum = строк из комментов при совпадении в таблице комментариев newsid с уже выбранным(цикл) id самой новости.

UPD

```
//запрос в базу
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id LIMIT {$n->start()},$pnumber ");

        //выводим результаты

    while (false!==($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))) {
//ПОДСТАВЛЯТЬ СТРОКУ НАДО В ЦИКЛЕ! ЕСЛИ ЗА ЦИКЛОМ, ОНА ТЕБЕ ТОЛЬКО 1 ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ВЫВЕДЕТ!
        $comnum = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news_comments` WHERE `newsid` = '".$res['id']."'"));

    ?>
```

Тут твой вывод бла бла бла бла бла

```
 <? 
// закрываем цикл, когда вывели все))
} ?>
```

Comment: Нет, ТС хотел необьяснимым чудо кодом выбирать комментарии к постам без уникального идентификатора :)

Comment: Я не экстрасенс) Я только учусь)) Я предположил, что надо это) Предложил вариант решения проблемы)<br /> Возможно, под "нет ID" он имел ввиду, что это общий лист со статьями.

Comment: Все может быть :)

Comment: все правильно это общий лист с статьями

Comment: ну т.е. подзапросом просто к запросу добавляйте чтото типа<br> SELECT COUNT(*) AS comments FROM comments WHERE id="id"

Comment: ну что на что горазд) моих познаний маловато будет, потому что я попутно занимаюсь очень многим, у меня конечно есть мечта забить на всё, и заняться чем то одним, но в наше время - "хочешь есть, умей вертеться" по этому чучуть там, побольше там, etc... по обстановке)
пример который я привёл попахивает быдлокодом, но по факту - он работает)

Comment: Нет, это не помогает. Просто я пока еще в mysql не силен.

Comment: Код вывода статей в студию) Я тебе напишу, куда это запихнуть, чтобы помогло)
Обновил, надеюсь доступно)))
Запрос можешь впихнуть свой)) С моим работать не будет:))